# Maven not working when 'mvn package' command is run

Tags: java, maven-3

I am working on a Spring mvc using Eclipse. Until now I was using ant to create war file. But now I switched to Maven. I have copied Maven 3.3 on my system and set system variables for Maven. It works fine, when I run Maven following command from command prompt:

```
mvn -version
```

I have created a pom.xml file in my Spring mvc app's root directory. I run Maven through command prompt, not through Eclipse. When I run following command:

```
mvn -X package
```

it shows following errors:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 22.590 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-06-16T12:52:16+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.mav
en.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.
org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/199.27.79.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to
read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:179)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:298)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:241)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecution(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:169)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecutions(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:131)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan(BuilderCommon.java:96)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:109)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:302)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:218)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:287)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:103)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to central
(https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/199.27.79.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:287)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to central (htt
ps://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/199.27.79.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:43)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
        at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/199.27.79.215] failed: Connection timed out: connec
t
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1066)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:960)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$GetTaskRunner.run(WagonTransporter.java:560)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute(WagonTransporter.java:427)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.get(WagonTransporter.java:404)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:447)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
        ... 37 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/199.27.79.215] fail
ed: Connection timed out: connect
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:140)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:318)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.execute(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:832)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:983)
        ... 46 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:239)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:123)
        ... 56 more
```

It says connection timed out, but my internet is running fine.

Comment: I am using maven 3.3.3

Comment: Then HTTPS should work out of the box. Are you using windows? My guess is that your firewall is blocking the access.

Answer (score 2):

`199.27.79.215` is not the right IP address for `repo.maven.apache.org`.  The right IP address is `23.235.40.215` *(as of 9/10/2015 from my desktop)*.  If I open a browser to https://199.27.79.215/, I get a web page which says `unknown domain: 199.27.79.215`.

The problem is that Maven is being run in an environment without a direct connection to the Internet.  Maven needs to be configured to go through the HTTP Proxy.  The Maven documentation for this is found [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html).  Here's the information...

> **Configuring a proxy**
>
> You can configure a proxy to use for some or all of your HTTP requests
>   with Maven. The username and password are only required if your proxy
>   requires basic authentication (note that later releases may support
>   storing your passwords in a secured keystore - in the mean time,
>   please ensure your settings.xml file (usually
>   ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml) is secured with permissions appropriate
>   for your operating system).
>
> The nonProxyHosts setting accepts wild cards, and each host not to
>   proxy is separated by the | character. This matches the JDK
>   configuration equivalent.
>
> ```
> <settings>
>   .
>   .
>   <proxies>
>    <proxy>
>       <id>example-proxy</id>
>       <active>true</active>
>       <protocol>http</protocol>
>       <host>proxy.example.com</host>
>       <port>8080</port>
>       <username>proxyuser</username>
>       <password>somepassword</password>
>       <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
>     </proxy>
>   </proxies>
>   .
>   .
> </settings>
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I found that setting my MAVEN_OPTS environment variable worked. Apparently JDK7 has some issues with it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5162

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the repository which is available at

```
repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/199.27.79.215]
```

and as the error says, maven is not able to reach that URL:

```
org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/199.27.79.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
```

Check your internet connection and make sure you are able to reach the repo. You can test it by trying to hit the URL in browser or by using curl

Comment: I have tried to open https://repo.maven.apache.org/199.27.79.215, but it shows 404 error.

Comment: Op says _but my internet is running fine_, so perhaps this should be a comment rather than an answer. Although it would be the cause of the error if he actually cannot reach the URL.

Comment: @VishalSuri You are using the https for maven so try this in browser:https://repo.maven.apache.org:443

Comment: It says:

Browsing for this directory has been disabled.
View this directory's contents on http://search.maven.org instead.
Find out more about The Central Repository.